# requestAnimationFrame is passing unexpected parameters in IE10

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-10, requestanimationframe

So I've been a good net citizen, using feature detection to see whether the browser supports `requestAnimationFrame` and only fall back to a `setTimeout`-based solution otherwise (something around the lines of [Paul Irish's famous post](http://paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/)).

```js
var NOW = Date.now || function () { return new Date.getTime(); };
var reqAnimFrame =
        window.requestAnimationFrame ||
        window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
        /*                        ... ||                     */
        function (callback) {
            setTimeout(function () { callback(NOW()); }, 1000 / 60);
        };

var previousTime = NOW();
function animStep(time) {
    var timePassed = time - previousTime;
    myCharacter.move(myCharacter.speed * timePassed);
    previousTime = time;
    reqAnimationFrame(animStep);
} 

// start the animation
reqAnimationFrame(animStep);
```

This worked great everywhere until Internet Explorer 10 came along. In IE10, the `time` parameter passed doesn't seem to have anything to do with the current time, screwing up the calculation of `timePassed`.

What's going on?

Comment: quite surprisingly... that would have been the first time that *Internet Explorer* deviates from the spec. I'm shocked!

Comment: @jAndy Well in this case, you could say they're ahead of the other browsers in *following* it.

Comment: And that is exactly the point: IE messed up for years and now they're trying to be good guy following the standards tightly. Hopefully it will balance out in the future.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

All (as far as I know) other browsers that implement `requestAnimationFrame` go by the specification in the (at the time of writing) current [*Working* Draft](http://www.w3.org/TR/animation-timing/):

> Let *time* be [the redraw time] expressed as the number of milliseconds since 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z.

That's representing time precisely like your `NOW()` does.

IE10 however [goes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh773174%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) by the spec in the current [*Editor's* Draft](http://dvcs.w3.org/hg/webperf/raw-file/tip/specs/RequestAnimationFrame/Overview.html):

> Let *time* be the result of invoking the [now method of the Performance interface](http://dvcs.w3.org/hg/webperf/raw-file/tip/specs/HighResolutionTime/Overview.html#dom-performance-now) within this context.

Which essentially means the number of milliseconds *since the browser loaded this page* (it also means the the measurement is more precise, since `performance.now` returns fractional milliseconds).

And thus when you calculate `timePassed` for the first time in IE10, you are getting something like negative 43 years.

Fortunately, because the value passed to the `requestAnimationFrame` callback has the same unit in either case, just a different point of reference, you can easily adjust to this.

There are three possibilities:

1. You could just throw away the very first animation step, using it *only* to set `previousTime`, but not doing anything else.
2. You could ignore the passed parameter and use your `NOW()` (or `performance.now`) every time, thus always having the same same point of reference.
3. Or you could change the start of the animation to this:

   ```js
   // start the animation
   reqAnimationFrame(function (t) {
       previousTime = t - (NOW() - previousTime);
       animStep(t);
   );
   ```

   This will make the calculation (including the first one) of `timePassed` correct no matter which spec the browser follows. And since it changes only the very first invocation, you don't have any additional overhead in the long run either.